# duda Python continue

Tags: python, bucle-for

Como puedo adaptar este programa para que funcione con una declaración continue?

**El programa tiene que utilizar un ciclo for para mostrar una palabra en vertical sin mostrar las vocales y en mayuscula**

```
palabra = input("Ingrese una palabra: ")
vocales='aeiou'

conversion = ''.join(letter for letter in palabra if letter not in vocales)
for x in str(conversion):
    print(x.upper())
```

Comment: Cuidado: tus preguntas están rozando a que quieres que se te haga la tarea. Ten en cuenta que **aquí no hacemos eso**. Y como se te mencionaba en la otra pregunta: no pongas títulos de tipo _duda con..._, _problema con..._, etc. Lectura recomendada: [los ingredientes de una buena pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433).

Comment: Eso lo entiendo y que titulo podria ser entonces? no estoy pidiendo la tarea porque la mayoria del ejercicio lo hice , estoy preguntando una duda si para eso Stackoverflow

Comment: El titulo debe ser una breve descripción de tu problema

Comment: Tienes claro para qué se usa el continue? Cómo estás intentando usarlo en tu código?

Comment: Este codigo que muestra? que esperas que muestre? si al final del print pones un salto de linea no hace lo que queres?

Comment: Dentro del ciclo examinas cada caracter. Preguntas si **no** cumple la condición; y en ese caso colocas `continue` para pasar al siguiente ciclo. No tienes un `else`, sencillamente colocas la impresión después del `if`.

Answer (score 2):

En realidad hay un problema de incompatibilidad entre lo  que has hecho y lo que buscas-

```
palabra = input("Ingrese una palabra: ")
vocales='aeiou'
```

hasta acá esta bien

```
#conversion = ''.join(letter for letter in palabra if letter not in vocales)
```

estla línea la marque como comentario porque no va.

```
for x  in palabra:
    if x in vocales:
        continue
    print(x.upper())
```

ahora recorremos la cadena y si la letra está en vocales que continue sino que muestre la letra